# Doing UI on a background thread

Tags: multithreading, opengl, window, language-agnostic, cross-platform

The SDL documentation for threading states:

> NOTE: You should not expect to be able to create a window, render, or receive events on any thread other than the main one.

The glfw documentation for glfwCreateWindow states:

> Thread safety: This function must only be called from the main thread.

I have read about issues regarding the glut library from people who have tried to run the windowing functions on a second thread.

I could go on with these examples, but I think you get the point I'm trying to make. A lot of cross-platform libraries don't allow you to create a window on a background thread.

Now, two of the libraries I mentioned are designed with OpenGL in mind, and I get that OpenGL is not designed for multithreading and you shouldn't do rendering on multiple threads. That's fine. The thing that I don't understand is why the rendering thread (the single thread that does all the rendering) *has to be the main one of the application*.

As far as I know, neither Windows nor Linux nor MacOS impose any restrictions on which threads can create windows. I do know that windows have affinity to the thread that creates them (only that thread can receive input for them, etc.); but still that thread does not *need* to be the main one.

So, I have three questions:

1. Why do these libraries impose such restrictions? Is it because there is some obscure operating system that mandates that all windows be created on the main thread, and so all operating systems have to pay the price? (Or did I get it wrong?)
2. Why do we have this imposition that you should not do UI on a background thread? What do *threads* have to do with windowing, anyways? Is it not a bad abstraction to tie your logic to *a specific thread*?
3. If this is what we have and can't get rid of it, how do I overcome this limitation? Do I make a `ThreadManager` class and yield the main thread to it so it can schedule what needs to be done in the main thread and what can be done in a background thread?

It would be amazing if someone could shed some light on this topic. All the advice I see thrown around is to just do input and UI both on the main thread. But that's just an arbitrary restriction if there isn't a technical reason why it isn't possible to do otherwise.

PS: Please note that I am looking for a cross platform solution. If it can't be found, I'll stick to doing UI on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not quite up to date on the latest releases of MacOS/iOS, as of 2020 Apple UIKit and AppKit were **not** thread safe. Only one thread can safely change UI objects, and unless you go to a lot of trouble that's going to be the main thread. Even if you do go to all the trouble of closing the window manager connection etc etc you're still going to end up with one thread only doing UI. So the limitation still applies on at least one major system.

While it's possibly unsafe to directly modify the contents of a window from any other thread, you can do software rendering to an offscreen bitmap image from any thread you like, taking as long as you like. Then hand the finished image over to the main thread for rendering. (The *possibly* is why cross platform toolkits disallow/tell you not to. Sometimes it might work, but you can't say why, or even that it will keep working.)

With Vulkan and DirectX 12 (and I think but am not sure Metal) you can render from multiple threads. Woohoo! Of course now you have to figure out how to do all the coordination and locking and cross-synching without making the whole thing slower than single threaded, but at least you have the option to try.

Adding to the excellent answer by Matt, with Qt programs you can use `invokeMethod` and `postEvent` to have background threads update the UI safely.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's highly unlikely that any of these frameworks actually care about which thread is the 'main thread', i.e., the one that called the entry point to your code.  The real restriction is that you have to do all your UI work on the thread that initialized the framework, i.e., the one that called SDL_Init in your case.  You will usually do this in your main thread. Why not?
2. Multithreaded code is difficult to write and difficult to understand, and in UI work, introducing multithreading makes it difficult to reason about when things happen.  A UI is a very stateful thing, and when you're writing UI code, you usually need to have a very good idea about what has happened already and what will happen next -- those things are often undefined when multithreading is involved.  Also, users are slow, so multithreading the UI is not really necessary for performance in normal cases.  Because of all this, making a UI framework thread-safe isn't usually considered beneficial. (multithreading compute-intensive parts of your rendering pipeline is a different thing)
3. Single-threaded UI frameworks have a dispatcher of some sort that you can use to enqueue activities that should happen on the main thread when it next has time.  In SDL, you use [SDL_PushEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent) for this.  You can call that from any thread.

Comment: (1) is not true for GLFW, and it is because of macOS being the only platform that requires window management on the main thread. https://discourse.glfw.org/t/multithreading-glfw/573/5